# clone でワンライナーってできますか？

Tags: php

```
$hoge = new Hoge();
(clone $hoge)->kansu();
```

というコードを実行したら

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
```

というエラーになってしまいます。
その場限りのclone オブジェクトなのでワンライナーで書きたいのですができますか？

@php5.6

Comment: `(new Hoge())->kansu();` とするのはどうでしょうか。なお、php7 では `(clone $hoge)->kansu();` はエラーにならず期待通りに動作します。

Comment: 既に取得したHogeオブジェクトに対して何らかの加工が加わり、そのオブジェクト状態をそのまま利用したいけど、利用することでオブジェクトにさらに加工が加わるのを避ける。という目的なので、ちょっと難しいですね。

php 7 だと動作するんですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと強引ですけど↓のようなものはいかがでしょうか？

```
$hoge = new Hoge();
current([clone $hoge])->kansu();
```

下記のように値を返すだけの関数があればそれを使うこともできます。

```
function ref($o)
{
    return $o;
}

$hoge = new Hoge();
ref(clone $hoge)->kansu();
```

Comment: current([clone $hoge])->kansu();
こちらの方法だとスッキリですね。ありがとうございます。